# Cannot write to STM32 (Cortex M4) ISERx, STIR Register

Tags: interrupt, cortex-m, stm32f4

I am trying to manually set the ISER0 and STIR registrs to invoke interrupt number 3 which is RTC Wakeup Interrup for educational purposes. Here is my code:

[image]

I step through the register contents, but somehow the code was not able to write to the ISER0 and STIR registers, as is shown below where i am trying to clear the ISER0 register.

[image]
Can someone please explain me what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. ISER has one bit for every exception, STIR takes exception number - 16.
2. In the second image you write 0 to the ISER register. That has no effect as described from both ARM architecture reference manual and STM32 M4 Programming Manual.
3. I would put a volatile on both register pointers declaration, but in this case I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: The issue is solved. Somehow, the stlink debug with openOCD was causing an issue with semihosting enabled to which i have no explanation for now. When I changed the debugging to STLink with SWV viewer, it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. Somehow, the stlink debug with openOCD was causing an issue with semihosting enabled to which i have no explanation for now. When I changed the debugging to STLink with SWV viewer, it worked ok...